# Proving there exists an isoemtry between 2 parameterized curves

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

> Is there an isometry of $\Bbb R^2$ taking the curve given by
>   $\alpha(t) = (1+\cos(t), 2+\sin(t))$ for $t \in [0, \pi]$ to the curve
>   given by $\beta = (t, \sin(t))$ for $t \in [0, c]$ where $c$ is some
>   constant?

In order to prove there's an isometry, must I prove that there exists a $2 \text{x} 2$ matrix $A$ so that $\beta(t) = A * \alpha(t)$. If I prove such a matrix doesn't exist, is that sufficient to prove that there isn't the existence of an isometry, or is there a different way to prove/disprove the existence of an isometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first thing I would do is sketch the two curves in the plane.

If by "isometry of $\mathbb R^2$" we mean an isometry under the usual Euclidean metric, then it suffices to show that the distances between the endpoints of each curve is not preserved except for a specific value of $c$; and then, in this case, show that the distance between an endpoint and the respective midpoint is not preserved.

Comment: so if I show that for any points $p, q$ on the curve, that the value of c for a specific $p$ and $q$ is different than the value of c for another $p$, $q$, that's enough to show that an isometry doesn't exist?

Comment: What I mean is that I have to show that $||\alpha(\pi/2)-\alpha(0)|| = ||\beta(c)-\beta(0)||$ for some value of $c$, and then show that this same value of $c$ doesn't work when I take the distance say, between the endpoints. When I prove this, there's no isometry, right?